# Solution to $0 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i [f(v_i+x) - f(v)]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

i am currently stuck and need some approval / disapproval.
Suppose i am given a strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $a_i$ between 0 and 1 and looking for a solution x of
\begin{equation*}
0=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i [f(v_i+x)-f(v)], \qquad v,v_i \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
I procced by applying Taylor expansion around v for $f(v_i +x)$
\begin{align*}
f(v_i+x)-f(v) = f'(\xi_i)(v_i+x-v)
\end{align*}
for some $\xi_i$ between both points and bound $f'(\xi)$ from below and above by constant $C^+,C^-$ globally for all $i$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
0 &\leq C^+ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(v_i+x-v)
\\
0 &\geq C^- \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(v_i+x-v)
\end{align*}
yielding 
\begin{align*}
x &\geq v-A^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i
\\
x &\leq v-A^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i,
\end{align*}
where A is the sum of all $a_i$
and thus 
\begin{equation*}
x = v-A^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i.
\end{equation*}

So, yeah. It somehow feels strange. Did I overlook something? I am pretty sure I did but I am stuck for hours...Suppose, that everything is OK with Taylor and finiteness of $f'$ and that the derivatives exist...

Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: what is $v$? Is it the vector of $v_i$?

Comment: Also, should the first equation be $f(v_i + x) - f(v_i)$?

Comment: Hi, i edited the question. $v$ and $v_i$ are real-valued. And the first equation is correct.

Comment: Shouldn't $f(v_i + x) - f(v) = f(v_i) - f(v) + x f'(\xi)$? It seems a little unclear how you arrived at your second equation.

Comment: Yes, if you expand around $v_i$, but expanding around $v$ would give: $f(v_i+x)=f(v)+f'(\xi)(v_i+x-v)$ doesn't it? It is somehow just the mean value theorem.

Comment: OK, I think the problem is this: The quantity $v_i + x - v$ may be positive or negative. So even if it's the case that $f'(\xi_i)\le C^+$, it doesn't necessarily follow that $\sum_i a_i f'(\xi_i) (v_i + x - v) \le C^+\sum_i a_i (v_i + x - v)$.